# How to change the display order of qt gui sink in gnuradio?

Tags: gnuradio

I create simple flow graph in gnuradio as below:

[image]

The expected output order is:

- 1.qt gui sink
- 2.frequency sink
- 3.time sink

But time sink appear first,then gui sink:

[image]

How to change the display order of qt gui sink in gnuradio?

Comment: I haven't run gnuradio in about 5 years... Could you check two things?  From memory, I believe it is either that the order you create the elements matter or (much more likely) there is an attribute on the objects.  I have a build job running, but it will take a long time to complete.  If you can check this we can get a proper answer written. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer,I confirmed it's nothing to do with `order you create the elements`.Also, I didn't find place to set `atrribute`.

Comment: Ok.  I am waiting for the build to complete.  I know I've done this before.  I should have an answer for you sometime tomorrow morning. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All QT GUI elements support a [GUI hint](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/GUI_Hint) which dictates how they are laid out in a grid.

> All of the QT GUI widgets and plots have a parameter called GUI Hint. This is used to arrange GUIs in the window, as well as assign them to tabs in a QT GUI Tab Widget.
>
> [image]
>
> The format is:
>
> (row, column, row span, column span)
>
> For example,
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks Phil, you beat me to it.  @kittygirl take note that you don't need to do this for every single element.  If you are creating complex views on a tab widget, you can simply set this for the collection of controls (the tab widget) rather than having to do it for every single control displayed.  As for me, I usually set the ones I care most about and evaluate if the autolayout "works" for the others before configuring every one of them.